# My content-type is being overwritten on my curl request

Tags: php, curl

EDIT: It turns out the data was being sent just fine, but viewing the body in PHP wasn't working correctly. See my answer for more info.

I'm attempting to post json data to a server.I just need the content-type to be json and the body to have a string in json format.
My problem is that the content-type is staying as text/html and no matter what I try I can't get that content-type to change. I read numerous stack overflow answers, and they all seem like they should work, but they don't. My code is below.

```
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));      
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
  curl_exec($ch);
```

On the receiving end I'm simply printing getallheaders and get_file_contents('file://phpinput').

Why isn't my content-type going through correctly?

Here is an example output if it helps:

```
string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2013 16:24:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4
Content-Length: 71
Content-Type: text/html

Array{"level1a":{"level2":{"a":2,"b":3}},"level2b":["111","333","999"]}' (length=273)
```

Comment: Why is there `Array` before your json?

Comment: The headers you quoted are from a reply, not a request. Request-headers don't contain "Server:".

Comment: Is there any way to see the request headers in PHP?
I would like to confirm that my curl is being sent correctly.
If not, is there a way to see the exact headers that a curl request is *going* to send out?

Comment: According to the php documentation, POSTFIELDS can either be a url encoded string or an array. I'm passing a string, but it isn't in a url get format... perhaps it doesn't know what to do with my json_encoded string.

If I can literally only pass a url_encoded string or an array, how the heck do I send a post with pure JSON in it?

Comment: I just added: "Content-Length: " . strlen($jsondata),
to the HTTPHEADER array. It didn't help, but I think it was something I was missing, regardless.
Here is a reference that reminded me: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl

Comment: Also to note: if i print out the json_encode, it does not contain the "array" at the beginning. I have no idea where that is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two php files, a client (client.php) and a server (server.php).

The server reads json requests and send back a (json) response.
Your client sends json to te server and reads the response.

You server.php need to be availible on a webserver `http://localhost/server.php`. 
You can run your client from the same or an other server `http://localhost/client.php`.
You can also run the client from the command line `php -f client.php`

server.php:

```
<?
// read json input
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$response = array('text'=>'Your name is: '.$input->{'name'});
header("Content-type: application/json");
// send response
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

client.php:

```
<?
$data = array('name'=>'Jason'); // input
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/server.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
list($headers, $content) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
$php = json_decode($content);
echo 'Response: ' . $php->text;
// if you want to know
var_dump($headers);
exit;
```

Comment: Have you tried this your self?
My concern was that when i printed the body it has "Array" pre-pending the JSON.
I was so concerned with the header output and the textual body, that I never considered simply trying to decode the body. That seems like the simplest solution.
I'll likely marks yours as correct as it is very concise.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out nothing was wrong.
I'm not sure where the "Array" part came from, but the API I was posting to received the data fine.
I think it would be great if someone posted a way to see exactly what is being sent out by a curl request, that way people could have an easier time troubleshooting than I had.